# HTML Agility Pack Find ids starting with

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am a completly noob on XPath, I am doing application to fetch data from a website, and I need to find 2 things:

1- all the span tags that start with: `ctl00_Main_GridView_lieutenants`

2- the href of the parent  tag on the span.... errr.. I will try to explain:

```
<a href="something.html"><span id="ctl00_Main_GridView_lieutenants_ctl03_lbl_nick">Text</span></a>
```

I need the Text and the link ;)

Comment: You might also look into using jQuery (instead)

Comment: One more reason not to use WebForms...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
//span[starts-with(@id, 'ctl00_Main_GridView_lieutenants')]
```

Selects all span which `@id` starts with `ctl00_Main_GridView_lieutenants`

```
//a[span[starts-with(@id, 'ctl00_Main_GridView_lieutenants')]]/@href
```

Selects all `@href` of `a` which have child `span` which `@id` starts with `ctl00_Main_GridView_lieutenants`